# Current Web Applications with bad user interfaces

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, interface, human-interface-guideline

I am looking for some web applications with bad user interfaces. I need to find an application that can be redesigned using some standard user interface principles.

Comment: It'll be great if you can provide more context on why you require examples of bad user interface.

Comment: I have a UI project that requires I select a web application with a bad UI and redesign. I can find good examples of websites with bad UI's, but I can't seem to find any web application with a UI that really needs to be fixed

Comment: The new Flickr.

Comment: I keep hearing the distinction being made between web apps and web pages (or sites). What distinguishes one from the other? It seems that at one time the number of pages had something to do with it, but we now see many sites that employ one lone long page and apps having more than one "page" (or context) like the GMail app that has three pages under its big red drop down thingie (Mail, Contacts, Tasks). So what really distinguishes a web app from a web page/site?

Comment: @MarjanVenema it's subjective, but I think the line tends to fall between web sites that are purely informational in nature (say, a restaurant site sharing their menu) vs. sites that are designed to allow the visitor to accomplish a task (gmail). But then there's also those that straddle the line...like Wikipedia.

Comment: As for the OP's question: As a UX professional, you should likely have the opinion that every web application you use has room for improvement. :)

Comment: @DA01: Ok thanks. So you could say there is no real distinction but each site is somewhere on a continuum from one extreme (static informational pages) to another (task oriented sites). Nice way of looking at it.

Answer (score 3):

Suggestion: Take a look at some banking or airline sites. These sites usually have such strict compliance issues compounded by very conservative leadership (which is a good thing when you are trusting them with you life or money, but not great for innovation). So, at the very least I bet you find a suitable outdated interface that is ripe for some redesign. (and chances are somebody in the organization has redesigned it but it will take a year or more to see the light of day).

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Being a SharePoint Consultant by profession, it is painful to admit that SharePoint handles all kinds of lists in a peculiar way. It is a completely different thing clicking the row than clicking the link. It took me a year (that is +2000 hours of work) before I knew how to professionally work with lists in SharePoint. From the looks of it, it’s not that bad – but working with it is a real pain for my customers and me trying to explain why this is. An example from Central Administration of SharePoint and Manage service applications. This is the start page, and notice the disabled ribbon control.

[image]

Upon selecting the row (and not the link), you enable the ribbon control.

[image]

However, if you would accidentally (or intentionally) click the link instead, you would be directed to the service itself.

[image]

On regular Office applications, you would only enable the ribbon in a context sensitive fashion, but to be redirected to a new page is confusing. Either move all the settings to the specific service page, or use another type of link to the service to make it undoubtedly clear that you will be moved to the service page. Preferably outside of the highlighted row itself.